# filteration in txt file in python

Tags: python

I have too many lines like this:

```
>ENSG00000100206|ENST00000216024|DMC1|2371|38568257;38570043|38568289;38570286
CTCAGACGTCGGGCCGACGCAAGGCCACGCGCGCGAACACACAGGTGCGGCCCCGGGCCA
CACGCACACCGTACAC
>ENSG00000001630|ENST00000003100|CYP51A1|3210|92134365|92134530
TATATCACAGTTTCTTTCTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTGAGACAGAGTTTTGCTCTTGTT
GCCCAGGCTGGAGTACAGTGACGCAATCTCGGCTCACTGCAACCTTTGCCTCCCAGGTTC
>ENSG00000100206|ENST00000216024|DMC1|2371|38568257;38570043|38568289;38570286
TTAACTATAATCCCACTGCCTATTTTTTTATTTCTAAAAATATCATAAAAAGACACAAAA
```

the first line(starting with `>`) is identifier and other lines are sequence and also each identifier has its own sequence. in the mentioned example, `ENSG00000100206` is name and `ENST00000216024` is isoform. in my file there are some identifier lines with the same name but everything else is different. 
I would like to get the longest sequence for each name and make a new file. meaning there would be only one repeat of each name (but with the longest sequence).
for the above example the results would be like this:

```
>ENSG00000100206|ENST00000216024|DMC1|2371|38568257;38570043|38568289;38570286
CTCAGACGTCGGGCCGACGCAAGGCCACGCGCGCGAACACACAGGTGCGGCCCCGGGCCA
CACGCACACCGTACAC
>ENSG00000001630|ENST00000003100|CYP51A1|3210|92134365|92134530
TATATCACAGTTTCTTTCTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTGAGACAGAGTTTTGCTCTTGTT
GCCCAGGCTGGAGTACAGTGACGCAATCTCGGCTCACTGCAACCTTTGCCTCCCAGGTTC
```

do you guys know how to do that in python?

Comment: start with some code that iterates over all of these lines.

Comment: So is not a code writing service. You have to show at least some effort by presenting what you have tried so far.

Comment: @matias elgart: No, don't. No need to write you own parser when a million better written ones exist.

Comment: @JulienD i was suggesting to OP to at least _try_ something, rather than ask for answers without trying.

Answer (score 1):

You can start by using Biopython to get a proper FASTA format parser: http://biopython.org/wiki/SeqIO

Then iterate over the records, and do what you want with them. This will save you not only the time to write a parser, but also will prevent you from doing it completely wrong.

Example from that very page:

```
from Bio import SeqIO
for record in SeqIO.parse("example.fasta", "fasta"):
    print(record.id)
```

Instead of a print, create a dict `{record.id: record.length}` that you update only if the length is longer.

Comment: True, but this is not an answer

Comment: I'm not going to write his code, and it wouldn't have fit in a comment, although I think it is useful. Moreover, I wouldn't like him to follow matias elgart 's advice in comments.