# filteration using separators in python

Tags: python, fasta

I have many lines like the following:

```
>ENSG00000003137|ENST00000001146|CYP26B1|72374964|72375167|4732
CGTCGTTAACCGCCGCCATGGCTCCCGCAGAGGCCGAGT
>ENSG00000001630|ENST00000003100|CYP51A1|91763679|91763844|3210
TCCCGGGAGCGCGCTTCTGCGGGATGCTGGGGCGCGAGCGGGACTGTTGACTAAGCTTCG
>ENSG00000003137|ENST00000412253|CYP26B1|72370133;72362405|72370213;72362548|4025
AGCCTTTTTCTTCGACGATTTCCG
```

In this example `ENSG00000003137` is `name` and `4732` which is the last one is `length`. as you see some names are repeated but they have different length. 
I want to make a new file in which I only have those with the longest length. meaning the results would be like this:

```
>ENSG00000003137|ENST00000001146|CYP26B1|72374964|72375167|4732
CGTCGTTAACCGCCGCCATGGCTCCCGCAGAGGCCGAGT
>ENSG00000001630|ENST00000003100|CYP51A1|91763679|91763844|3210
TCCCGGGAGCGCGCTTCTGCGGGATGCTGGGGCGCGAGCGGGACTGTTGACTAAGCTTCG
```

I have made this code to split but don't know how to make the file I want:

```
file = open(“file.txt”, “r”)
for line in file:
   if line.startswith(“>”):
       line = line.split(“|”)
```

Comment: Just for reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40952471/filteration-in-txt-file-in-python. You probably mean "filtering", by the way.

Comment: This is a FASTA format file; records can span multiple lines, take that into account. How large a dataset are we talking about here? You can track names and sizes in a dictionary, and then make a *second* pass to write out the new file.

Comment: file is 220 MB.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to read the file twice; the first time round, track the largest  size per entry:

```
largest = {}
with open(inputfile) as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('>'):
            parts = line.split('|')
            name, length = parts[0][1:], int(parts[-1])
            largest[name] = max(length, largest.get(name, -1))
```

then write out the copy in a second pass, but only those sections whose name and length match the extracted largest length from the first pass:

```
with open(inputfile) as f, open(outpufile, 'w') as out:
    copying = False
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('>'):
            parts = line.split('|')
            name, length = parts[0][1:], int(parts[-1])
            copying = largest[name] == length
        if copying:
            out.write(line)
```

Comment: That's clever. But if two entries have the same length, they will both be copied to the output file, right?

Comment: @HåkenLid: yes, then both will be picked. You could remove the entry from the dictionary, I suppose, when you find a match, then test if `name` is in `largest` next time.

Comment: @HåkenLid: however, the question states that only those with the longest length should be copied, implying that if the max length is present multiple times, you want all those entries copied.

Comment: In that case, you can raise an exception if there's already an entry with the same length in the initial pass. Sometimes the actual data is not exactly as you expected.

Comment: @bzmby: then you may want to add a `if largest.get(name) == length: raise ValueError('Found same length {} twice for {}'.format(length, name))` in the first pass to be absolutely certain.

Answer (score 0):

you have to do two types of handling in the loop, one that compares your 'length', and one that stores the CGTA when its needed. I wrote an example for you that reads those into dicts:

```
file = open("file.txt", "r")
myDict = {}
myValueDict = {}
action = 'remember'
geneDict = {}

for line in file:
    if line.startswith(">"):
        line = line.rstrip().split("|")
        line_name = line[0]
        line_number = int(line[-1])
        if line_name in myValueDict:
            if myValueDict[line_name] < line_number:
                action = 'remember'
                myValueDict[line_name] = line_number
                myDict[line_name] = line
            else:
                action = 'forget'
        else:
            myDict[line_name] = line
            myValueDict[line_name] = line_number
    else:
        if action == 'remember':
            geneDict[line_name] = line.rstrip()


for key in myDict:
    print(myDict[key])

for key in geneDict:
    print(geneDict[key])
```

this ignores the lower length items. you can now store those dicts any way you want.